# What happens to the Planck distribution if the temperature is set to zero?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, photons, bose-einstein-condensate, virtual-particles

## BE Problem

I am currently working on modelling the density of states and optical conductivity of graphene utilizing the GW algorithm. In calculating the exchange self energy of the system, the formula I am currently using is

$$f(w,T) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{\omega}{T}}-1}$$

where the planck constant and the boltzmann constant $k$ is set to 1. To conservative bosonic particles, such as the core of helium-4, then it is believed to form a Bose-Einstein Condensate. I am dealing with the non-conservative bosonic particles, such as photons and phonons.

What would happen if I set the temperature $T$ equals to zero for the non-conservative bosons? My advisor believes that there would be no Bose-Einstein Condensate because the boson can pop in and out of the system. Is this true? If it is, what happens to the bosonic particles at the--or at least near--zero temperature?

---

### Update and Edit

I've consulted my adviser and my colleagues, and this is the result. In no way that this is the solution, but it is one step further nonetheless. I've made a model of the BE distribution and it follows similarly to the image in the middle:

[image: MB, BE, and FD Distributions]
<sub>(source: [universe-review.ca](https://universe-review.ca/I13-23-dist.jpg))</sub>

What I did is vary T = 1 K, 0.1 K, and 0.01 K in Scidavis (a numerical software on linux, if you are wondering). As the T decreases, the graph gets steeper and steeper; analytically, inserting T = 0 in the formula would equal to infinity. This of course, is the puzzling question.

Since I am required to put this in my calculation, my adviser suggested that at T = 0 the distribution equals to 0, where we assumed that the photons disappear after being absorbed by the electrons.

Why does this matter so much? Because I am now calculating the self energy of the system and the final formula requires a Hilbert transform integration from -inf to +inf. If there are anyone working on this problem or something similar, this would really help.

Comment: If you set T=0, then the third law of thermodynamics starts crying.

Comment: Do explain @CuriousOne, and perhaps shine a light on what happens on the distribution if I set T = 0..

Comment: I think there's room for an interesting analysis of what happens in the limit as $T\to 0^+$.

Comment: I did try to work it out with my colleagues, and got stuck yesterday. Tried L'hopital, but still ended up with either with 0/0 or 0/infinity. 

Also searched online for this, and still nothing up to now @DavidZ

Comment: It seems clear to me that the entire thing will just go to zero. What are you wondering about?

Comment: so then the particle would vanish at that temperature? shouldn't the number of particles would be conserved at all times? Or am I incorrect? @Danu

Comment: For T->0 naive theories break down...

Comment: @M. Avicenna Naradipa: No, the number of photons/phonons will not be conserved: when we assume that the temperature goes down, that means that the system is connected to a thermostat or something like that, so energy (and photons/phonons) can flow there.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that you just cannot tell the difference between a Bose condensate and nothing in this case. What will change if you add some photons or phonons with zero energy to the system? No characteristics of the system will change. So it seems to me we have no criterion to decide if there is a Bose condensate in this case, and what's more important, it does not matter.

Comment: You will get nothing all right, but it can never be a BEC because there is no way the photons can achieve equilibrium without interacting.

Comment: @SuperCiocia : I am not sure I understand this. First, "You will get nothing all right, but it can never be a BEC" - but there is no difference between "nothing" and BEC in this case, so why do I get "nothing", but not BEC? Second, "there is no way the photons can achieve equilibrium without interacting" - but I would say photons interact with the thermostat and thus achieve equilibrium.

Comment: In order to be a BEC you need to have a macroscopic occuation of a single quantum state, and you must be in equilibrium. At $T=0$, there *are no photons left in a resonator*. What is the meaning of calling "nothing" a BEC? The interactions with the cavity walls do not count the thermalisation needed for a BEC -- you need interparticle thermalisation to achieve a non-zero chemical potential. Photon-photon interactions are very low, unless enhanced by a non-linear medium (this is exactly how they *do* achieve BEC of photons).

Comment: @SuperCiocia : "At $T=0$, there are no photons left in a resonator." Of course, you can take such a position. That does not mean one cannot take an opposite position: "At $T=0$, there are a lot of photons in the ground state in a resonator." These two positions seem mutually contradictory, but neither of them (strongly) contradicts  experimental results, as photons in the ground state are (pretty much) undetectable. Let me also remind you that the issue of the energy of empty space is pretty controversial (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmological_constant_problem).

Comment: I don't see where you're going with this. A BEC is a *phase transition* driven essentially by the thermal de Broglie wavelength becoming comparable with the interparticle separation. You cannot define such a thing for thermal photons in a cavity. The cosmological constant problem concerns zero point energies, so it would also affect atomic BECs.

Comment: @SuperCiocia: B.-E. condensation is indeed a phase transition, but the OP mentions B.-E. condensate, which is a phase. I don't know why it cannot be defined for photons. Their wavelength can be arbitrarily large. "The cosmological constant problem concerns zero point energies, so it would also affect atomic BECs" - And technically it does affect atomic BECs, but it does not matter in that case, as the relevant zero point energy is negligible compared to mass (times c^2).

Comment: I don’t know what else to say other what I’ve already said, anything else I say is just going to be a repetition. Thermal photons do not Bose condense. The number of particles is not conserved so you cannot have a critical number.  If you look at the literature, only very specific snd well engineered systems of photos at referred to as BEC. I.e.  a phase with the macroscopic occupation of a single state.

Answer (score 1):

The Bose-Einstein occupancy at energy $E$ is given by:
$$ f_{\mathrm{BE}}  = \frac{1}{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{E-\mu}{k_BT}}-1}.$$

The chemical potential $\mu$ is the Lagrange multiplier associated with a fixed particle number $N$. What it means is that you can vary the temperature $T$, and $\mu(T$) will also vary so as to conserve your total number of particles $N$.

**Photons do not have a chemical potential**, and indeed your first formula is the BE occupancy with $\mu = 0$ and $E \propto \omega$.

Thermal  photons **do  not**  become  quantum  degenerate: as $T\rightarrow 0$, photons **vanish** instead of forming a condensate. Indeed, black-body radiation ceases for an object at $T=0$.

A zero chemical potential means photons do not thermalise, which the *key* to achieve *equilibrium* and hence Bose-Einstein condensation. A laser isn't a BEC -- it's a coherent state all right, but it is *not* in equilibrium. The chemical potential stuff is derived in the context of equilibrium thermodynamics. So lasers are a completely different story.

In order to achieve true BEC in photons, you need to introduce photon-photon interactions, leading to photon thermalisation and a non-zero chemical potential. This has been achieved in nonlinear microcavities, dye-filled cavities and other forms of materials that interact *with* the photons thereby mediating the interaction *amongst* the photons.